# Why is my python not installed properly even though I have no error?

Tags: python

I have no admin privileges in this system, I was following the way to install python through zip file as described in [Install Python on Windows without Admin access](https://zwbetz.com/install-python-on-windows-without-admin-access/).
I got no error while doing this but the python version check still says `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.
I checked my environment variables and the user variables had the PYTHON_HOME variable. What to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We're not going to go off-site and read through a whole tutorial just to understand what you're trying to do. In any case, have you modified your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: It's not in your PATH then. Either try `python3 -version` or do everything again.

Comment: at start you may have to use `C:\full\path\to\python` and later you have to add `C:\full\path\to\ ` (without `python`) to `PATH`.

Comment: @Chris: While in general I agree with you, in this case the offsite reference is minimal, so it's not that big of a deal IMO.

Comment: @furas that worked

Comment: @martineau i considered that before mentioning it here